# symbol lookup error with latest gazebo(1.5.0-1~precise)/drcsim(2.1.0-1~precise) from .debs

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Since I (apt-get) upgraded, I get

```
gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/drcsim-2.1/plugins/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6gazebo9transport9PublisherC1ERKSsS3_j
```

with gazebo(1.5.0-1~precise)/drcsim(2.1.0-1~precise) installed from .debs on my Ubuntu 12.04/AMD64 machine. It ran without problems before, so this appears to be a bug. Is this happening to anyone else?

/edit: Happens for example when starting default atlas:

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1737/symbol-lookup-error-with-latest-gazebo(1.5.0-1%7Eprecise)/drcsim(2.1.0-1%7Eprecise)-from-.debs/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 473 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on 2013-03-12**:
I can reproduce this in a 12.04 32bit system. It was also the case with the prerelease binaries from the last couple of days. The problem is on the drcsim side. I built drcsim (2.2) from source and got it to work, though. You beat me to posting the question :-)

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on 2013-03-12**:
A minimal test to reproduce is to run **gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so**

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-03-12**:
Got similar problem here. Cant start Gazebo now after today's update....

**Comment by [danny.brown](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/255/danny.brown/) on 2013-03-12**:
Getting same errors

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-20**:
HI. I got the same message. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like you were unlucky enough to update in between the release of gazebo 1.5.0 and drcsim 2.2.0.

We're working through the drcsim 2.2.0 release now and expect it to be out soon.

In the meantime, I suggest that you roll back your gazebo installation by grabbing a 1.4.0 .deb from [the archive](http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/), e.g. something like should do the trick on a 64-bit machine:

```
wget http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/gazebo_1.4.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get remove -y gazebo gazebo-prerelease
sudo dpkg -i gazebo_1.4.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -y drcsim
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danny.brown](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/255/danny.brown/) on 2013-03-12**:
How do I roll back the installation?

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-03-12**:
I updated my answer to provide a technique.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

drcsim 2.2.0 has been released.  So you should be able to fix your system like so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drcsim
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [superawesomepanda](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/259/superawesomepanda/) on 2013-03-12**:
When will it be released for precise i386?

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-03-12**:
Starting with drcsim 2.2.0, we're incorporating the AtlasBehaviorLibrary from Boston Dynamics, which provides walking and balancing control of the Atlas robot.  This library is provided to us as a binary-only shared object, and is currently available only in 64-bit.  Until that changes, we won't be building drcsim for 32-bit machines.  You can build from source on a 32-bit machine if you exclude the AtlasBehaviorLibrary.

**Comment by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on 2013-03-21**:
@gerkey: found the answer to my question on the other thread.  We need to post that DRCsim now requires a 64-bit system.  Advise that this be placed under a 'requirements' page for DRCsim, which I believe is currently absent.